# Как преобразовать нормали к вершинам в нормали к полигону в шейдере

Tags: opengl

В вертексный шейдер мне поступают нормали к вершинам объекта и когда я передаю эти нормали в фрагментный шейдер, используя метод освещения Фонга, объект получается плавно освещён [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Но мне нужно сделать режим освещения, в котором полигоны будут освещены так, чтобы полигон был одного, сплошного цвета, для понимания, я хочу сделать максимально простое освещение как в режиме редактора Blender 3D.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я понимаю что нужно просто сложить 3 нормали полигона и нормализировать, но проблема в том что я не могу обратиться сразу к этим трём нормалям из вершинного шейдера. Вот и возникает вопрос: Можно ли как-то реализовать автоматический подсчёт нормали к полигону, из нормалей к вершинам в шейдерах. Вести подсчёт заранее не вариант, так как я использую glDrawElements.

Comment: *"максимально простое освещение"* - ¿а зачем тогда метод освещения Фонга? *"понимаю что нужно просто сложить 3 нормали полигона и нормализировать"* - это нужно было бы делать для Фонга, а для простого затенения, как на второй картинке, не нужны ни нормали к вершинам, ни их интерполяция. По трем точкам треугольника определяете угол падения света и затемняете соответственно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, примерно по такой технике я и постарался сделать (в ответах). Просто я ещё так себе разбираюсь в OpenGl и вообще впервые на нём работаю (курсач на первом курсе делаю), так что извиняюсь за некомпетентность, и ещё раз спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вертексный шейдер:

```
  (...)
  viewPosition = (model * vec4(aVer, 1.0)).xyz;
  (...)
```

Фрагментный шейдер:

```
  (...)
  vec3 xTangent = dFdx( viewPosition );
  vec3 yTangent = dFdy( viewPosition );
  norm = normalize( cross( xTangent, yTangent ) )
  (...)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересное решение! )

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это не сработает. Даже если как-то извратиться и усреднить, то всё равно средняя нормаль одного треугольника и другого на 1 стороне куба будут разными.

Так что лучше всего передавайте по классике - по 1 нормали на каждую вершину каждого треугольника.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже решил данную проблему немного иначе. Будет в ответах на вопрос